# how to center horizontal scroller on super-wide web page?

Tags: css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Trying to figure out how to create a cross-browser web page of width: 1500%; that first opens in the center and not to the left.
I've searched online and found only one reference (here at stackoverflow) where someone was getting this effect but wanted to change it.  He/she didn't post their original code.

I've tried html center tags, css text-align: center; negative margins and paddings, positioning, html a name tags (only good for verticals I guess).  margin: auto; helps in Safari, but not in the others.

Anyone have any ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use javascript:

```
document.getElementById​​("scroller").scrollLeft = 100;​
```

Depending on the page structure and size you may see the left of the page first, but in that case you should be able to hide the content until after the scroll position is set.